5 trusted users on Cryptography - is this a problem?
We've now got only 5 trusted users on Crypto (as of 2015-12-28). Do we see this as an issue?
To be precise, trusted users have the following priviledges:

Voting to delete answers with score of -1 or lower
Voting to undelete answers except those deleted by a moderator
Voting to delete questions with a score of -3 or lower immediately after they are closed
Editing tag wikis without needing approval


I thought about this too when we were still in beta, but now that there are three active mods I don't think it really is an issue.

True, I think the mods can keep up with our question rate, even with the additional attraction by the new site design. Note that (only :P) one of the mods is actually a trusted user himself. So that still leaves only 7 persons to perform these actions.

I can’t edit the post myself; should the tag be spelt “privileges”?

@alexwlchan Usually yes, but there is an issue with the current site design so we cannot vote for your changes. Thanks for the heads-up, changed accordingly.

Still 2.5k to go... looking at my rep graph, I should get there in about 5 months at this rate. :)

Side-Note: Only 11 users (everyone above 10k + e-sushi) can actually see deleted answers...

Might be me… but this potential issue wouldn’t be one if people would increase their voting efforts. I mean, merely 10 people managed to drop 1000+ votes in here. Since some have been around for more than a year, I can’t ignore the feeling this could be enhanced just a little bit. (I tend to see more people commenting than voting each and every day.)

@e-sushi Then again, it seems we get quite some votes from followers not posting questions or answers - we owe some people (especially those below 1K of rep) some gratitude!

Indeed. If it were’t for them, things would definitely look more like an issue.

Related: The Three Cryptographers Problem

...aaaand I just hit 20k, two days short of the predicted five months. Pretty nicely extrapolated, if I may say so myself. :)

I would say it’s not really an issue (yet) as Crypto.SE tends to be a bit less noisy and less chaotic compared to sites like (for example) StackOverflow. Nevertheless, it surely wouldn’t hurt to drop votes more frequently.
After all, it’s the votes that sum up to the user score.
If you check the voting stats, it shows that merely 10 people managed to drop 1000+ votes in here. Since some users have been around for more than a year, I can’t ignore the feeling this could be enhanced just a little bit. (I tend to see more people commenting than voting each and every day.)
In the end, I can only repeat what I said before in another answer to a somewhat related question…

…
Your vote is your voice… show members that their question or answer is a good one and that you appreciate the effort they’ve put into it.

Upvoting only takes a single click – and comes with a free, nice feeling of having shared some kudos.

As the “Winterbash 2015” is still ongoing, maybe each user reading this should ask himself/herself : Did I manage to earn a “vote early, vote often” hat this year? If not, ask yourself why not… it’s pretty easy to gain by simply  casting a total of 250 votes on any seven consecutive UTC days. Besides that, it would surely help pave the way towards resolving potential issues arising from the currently rather low number of “trusted users”.
(As an aside I would like to note that I personally “trust” more users around here than their individual user scores might indicate. Too bad the system doesn’t take into account such personal opinions.)

+1, every motivation to vote is important. People: please vote on questions about voting!

I never thought about the importance to vote, I'll try to vote more often. Thanks for this question and answer, made me understand more about Crypto.SE community.

Don't expect them to be all upvotes. Downvotes along with a comment are important to improve the accuracy and validity of the site's content. I like that there are two users with more downvotes than upvotes. Sometimes though, there is a post that has some problems, but could be good with editing either from others or from the OP. In that case I'm torn and refrain from voting until it's fixed (either by me or others).

@ArtjomB. I certainly didn’t want to imply that we should only drop upvotes… that would be as unhealthy for the site as not voting at all. Besides, I guess we both agree that there are times where it’s hard to find Q&As that are worth upvoting in the first place; so we don’t… and that’s good. The only thing I wanted to express is that – assuming a Q or A is “OK” – we should think about rewarding that just like we share our opinion when something is “not OK”. Fact is, most forget that upvotes are the SE way to say thanks… and we’ve all seen those “thank you” comments on Qs or As with 0 votes.
